# Residue of 1/(z-sin(z)) at z=0

Tags: residue-calculus

**I am to find the residue of f(z)=1/(z-sin(z)) at z=0.**
I am confused as to which method to use.
Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: $$z-\sin z=z-\left(z-\frac16z^3 +O(z^5)\right)=O(z^3)$$Can you find the residue now?

Answer (score 1):

One has
$$z-\sin z={z^3\over6}\left(1-{z^2\over20}+?z^4\right)$$
and therefore
$${1\over z-\sin z}={6\over z^3}\left(1+{z^2\over20}+?z^4\right)=6{1\over z^3}+{3\over10}{1\over z}+?z\ .$$
It follows that the residue in question is ${3\over10}$.

(Each question mark above represents a certain power series which is convergent in a neighborhood of $0$.)